# Read value of product's custom options in custom script of Opencart 2.x

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

Is is possible to read variable value of custom option using key value pair?

I am trying to read option value for a product in custom function.I am able to read value by referring it with array index like below

`$option = array_filter($this->request->post['option']);
$product_serial_no = $option['93'] ;`

I get magic array index `$option[93]` by reading variable value in Neatbean debug mode.

[image]

**But option index is changing for different products thus I want to read value of variable 'Serial Number' using something like associative array.
Is it possible?**

The options on product page look like below image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are viewing the product page and say you select some of the options and click "add to cart" the post will carry this array

$_POST['option'] = array(93 => '22222') (as you have presented in your example)

the 93 is the `$product_option_id` and it allows you to pull all the information you need with this request:

```php
$product_id = $this->request->post['product_id'];
foreach ($this->request->post['option']) as $product_option_id => $value) {
    $option_query = $this->db->query("SELECT 
    po.product_option_id, 
    po.option_id, 
    od.name, 
    o.type 
    FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option po 
    LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "option` o ON (po.option_id = o.option_id) 
    LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "option_description od ON (o.option_id = od.option_id)
    WHERE po.product_option_id = '" . (int)$product_option_id . "' 
    AND po.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' 
    AND od.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'");

    print_r($option_query->row);
}
```

This info should be sufficient enough to do any manipulations with options.

if the option has type of `select` or `radio` you may want to query also the possible variations like this

```php
//... put this inside the foreach loop, listed above right after print_r($option_query->row);
if ($option_query->row['type'] == 'select' || $option_query->row['type'] == 'radio') {
    $option_value_query = $this->db->query("SELECT 
    pov.option_value_id, 
    ovd.name, 
    pov.quantity, 
    pov.subtract, 
    pov.price, 
    pov.price_prefix, 
    pov.points, 
    pov.points_prefix, 
    pov.weight, 
    pov.weight_prefix 
    FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option_value pov 
    LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "option_value ov ON (pov.option_value_id =     ov.option_value_id) 
    LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "option_value_description ovd ON (ov.option_value_id = ovd.option_value_id) 
    WHERE pov.product_option_value_id = '" . (int)$value . "' 
    AND pov.product_option_id = '" . (int)$product_option_id . "' 
    AND ovd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'");

    print_r($option_value_query->row);
}
```

And in case you have a checkbox (like in the example above)

```php
//...also place this in the loop foreach in the code above.
if ($option_query->row['type'] == 'checkbox' && is_array($value)){
    foreach ($value as $product_option_value_id) {
        $option_value_query = $this->db->query("SELECT 
        pov.option_value_id, 
        pov.quantity, 
        pov.subtract, 
        pov.price, 
        pov.price_prefix, 
        pov.points, 
        pov.points_prefix, 
        pov.weight, 
        pov.weight_prefix, 
        ovd.name 
        FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option_value pov 
        LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "option_value_description ovd ON (pov.option_value_id = ovd.option_value_id) 
        WHERE pov.product_option_value_id = '" . (int)$product_option_value_id . "' 
        AND pov.product_option_id = '" . (int)$product_option_id . "' 
        AND ovd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'");

        print_r($option_value_query->row);
    }
}
```

You can view this exact code in `system/library/cart/cart.php`

hope this helps.

Comment: I will try this tomorrow and will give you feedback.

Comment: Yes, with your code I got it working. Now I am getting Serial number as follows

` if (array_search('Serial Number',$option_query->row) ){
    (int)$serialnumber_id = $product_option_id;
    }
   // print_r($option_query->row); `
 I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: I even simplified it as follows

`$product_options   = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductOptions($ctrl->request->post['product_id']);
    foreach ($product_options as $eachoption) {
                if (array_search('Serial Number',$eachoption)) {
                (int)$serialnumber_id = $eachoption['product_option_id'];
         }
    }
`

Comment: cool, this is a standard way of getting options so you can modify it to fit your needs. enjoy!